# Updating / adding a value for a table

Tags: list-manipulation

Having a table given by, let's say

`data = {a,b,c,d},{e,f,g,h}`

how can I update `data` in a simple way

`data = Something[data]`

to display

`data = {a,b,c,d, operation[a,b,c,d]},{e,f,g,h, operation[e,f,g,h]}`

for a given function "`operation`"?

Specifically, I'm finding solutions for an expression `function == 1` using a `RandomSearch`, but I'd like to display also the resulting value that is close to `target` in each search:

```
target = 1

solutionCandidates =
  Table[NMinimize[{Abs[(function[var1, var2, var3] -
         target)^2], var1min < var1 < var1max, var2min < var2 < var2max, var3min < var3 < var3max}, {var1, var2, var3},
    Method -> {"RandomSearch", "RandomSeed" -> i,
      "SearchPoints" -> 10}], {i, 10}];

solutions = Select[solutionCandidates, #[[1]] < 10^-10 &][[All, 2]];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
data = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}};

{##, operation @ ##} & @@@ data
```

> ```
> {{a, b, c, d, operation[a, b, c, d]}, 
>  {e, f, g, h, operation[e, f, g, h]}}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Try `Map` !

As a simple example

```
func = # . # &
Map[Join[#, {func[#]}] &, {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g,h}}, 1]
(*{{a, b, c, d, a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2}, {e, f, g,h,e^2 + f^2 + g^2 + h^2}}*)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
data = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}}
f[k_List] := {Sequence @@ k, f @@ k}
```

Map this function on each data item or as required.

```
f /@ data
```

> {{a, b, c, d, f[a, b, c, d]}, {e, f, g, h, f[e, f, g, h]}}

Answer (score 3):

```
lst = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}}
Append[#, operation[#]] & /@ lst
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `Query`

```
data = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}};

Query[All, {Apply[Sequence], Apply[operation]}] @ data
```

gives

```
{{a, b, c, d, operation[a, b, c, d]},
 {e, f, g, h, operation[e, f, g, h]}}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
data = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}};
```

Using `ComapApply` (new in 14.0)

```
ComapApply[{Sequence, op}] /@ data
```

returns

```
{{a, b, c, d, op[a, b, c, d]}, 
{ e, f, g, h, op[e, f, g, h]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `MapThread`:

```
data = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}};

MapThread[Append, {#, operation @@@ #}] &@data

(*{{a, b, c, d, operation[a, b, c, d]}, {e, f, g, h, operation[e, f, g, h]}}*)
```

Also, using `Flatten`:

```
Flatten[{##, operation[##]}] & @@@ data

(*{{a, b, c, d, operation[a, b, c, d]}, {e, f, g, h, operation[e, f, g, h]}}*)
```